# Unable to generate Scaffolding controller in asp.net5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am getting below error when I try to run From :

**c:\visual studio 2015\Projects\AppTest\src\AppTest**

```
PM> dnx  gen controller -name BooksController --dataContext MyDBContext --model Book
Finding the generator 'controller'...
dnx : Could not load file or assembly 'AppTest' or one of its dependencies. General Exception (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131500).
```

I am New to .Net and I am not able to figure it out. I tried updating webtools of VS2015 also still No luck. Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You try use *command line* scaffolding, which is dropped before RC1 (I'm not sure in beta7 or beta8). There are only scaffolding in Visual Studio. To be able to see the corresponding scaffolding dialog you have to add some packages in the dependencies of the `project.json`. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35240651/315935) for more details.

After that you can select Controllers folder in the Solution Explore of Visual Studio 2015, opens the context menu and choose "Add" / "Controller...". If your project have all required dependencies then you will see "MVC 6 Controller with views, using Entity Framework" which you can to choose and to click "Add" button. The next dialog contains additional options which corresponds the options of old `dnx gen controller` utility.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and i solved it doing the following steps:

1. Make sure the assembly you are referencing and the MVC project are targeting the same framework versions.

By default, the "frameworks" section of the file project.json in a new ASP.NET Core MVC project has the folowing values:

```
"frameworks": {
   "dnx451": { },
   "dnxcore50": { }}
```

And the "frameworks" section in the project.json file of a new Class Library is created as follows:

```
"frameworks": {
"net451": { },
"dotnet5.4": {
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
    "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
    "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
    "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
    "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
  }
}}
```

You see, a class library is not targeting the same framework version of the MVC Project. You have to replace "dotnet.5.4" on the class library's project.json file with "dnxcore50", to match the ones used in the MVC project.

```
"frameworks": {
"net451": { },
"dnxcore50": {
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
    "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
    "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
    "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
    "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
  }
}}
```

After that, save the package.json file and let Visual Studio do it's magic to rebuild the package.

I tried to replace the "dnxcore50" with "dotnet5.4" in the MVC Project but it didn't work. Some other assemblies referenced in the MVC Project didn't work with this framework version and a i had a build error.

2. Make sure you are using the same version of Entity Framework on both assemblies.

IF you want to use EF7, fust run update-package EntityFramwork.Core -Pre for both assemblies and you should be good.

3. Since to scaffold the controller you need a DbContext, make sure you configured the DbContext you want to use in the ConfigureServices method inside the Startup.cs class.

Should be like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:MyContextConnection:ConnectionString"])
                .MigrationsHistoryTable("MyContextMigrations")
                .MigrationsAssembly("MyContextAssembly"));

        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

4. Don't forget to put you connection string in the appsettings.json file or else VS will throw another error.

I did this and i was good to go, i hope this solution works for you.